# I wrote a recurring function to apply a user function on every non-array member of given unknown depth array

Tags: php

please tell me how I can improve this code:

```
<?php
class TEST {
 function awalkstr($func,$a) {
  $args = func_get_args(); array_shift($args);array_shift($args);
  foreach ($a as &$val) {
   if (!is_array($val)) $val = call_user_func_array($func,array_merge(array($val),$args));
   else $val = call_user_func_array(__METHOD__,array_merge(array($func),array($val),$args));
  }
  $a = array_filter($a,function ($v) {return isset($v);});
  return($a);
 }
 function upper_reverse_add($str,$add) {
  return (strlen($str)==2) ? null : $add.strtoupper(strrev($str));
 }
}

$test = new TEST();
$testarr = array(
    'uk'=>'london',
    array(
        'us'=>'ny',
        array(
            'california'=>'la',
            array(
                'tokyo',
                array('paris'),
                'rome'
            ),
            'moscow'
        ),
        'dublin',
        array(
            'berlin',
            array('warsaw')
        )
    ),
    'madrid',
    'lapaz'
);
print_r($test->awalkstr(array($test,'upper_reverse_add'),$testarr,'teststr-'));
?>
```

> ```
> Array (
> [uk] => teststr-NODNOL
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => teststr-OYKOT
>                         [1] => Array
>                             (
>                                 [0] => teststr-SIRAP
>                             )
>
>                         [2] => teststr-EMOR
>                     )
>
>                 [1] => teststr-WOCSOM
>             )
>
>         [1] => teststr-NILBUD
>         [2] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => teststr-NILREB
>                 [1] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => teststr-WASRAW
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>     )
>
> [1] => teststr-DIRDAM
> [2] => teststr-ZAPAL )
> ```

Comment: What's wrong that you want to improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some better formatting for your code. The [PEAR coding standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) are a good place to start.